# How can I run a function with a specific duration of time?

Tags: python, time

I am new to python and I wonder how can we set a specific time for a function to run.

Considering here I have a dataframe with 891 rows called **df** which has a column name **body_text** I want to perform a function call summary(to summary the text) through the row of dataframe and store them into a new dataframe called **df_summary**. Here my goal is to set a function **summary** to run at most for 2mins it will be good if it can finish before 2mins and move to the next iteration. In case it is not, I want to call the other function name **preprocess** instead of the function **summary** that cannot finish within 120s.

Consider we already created the **df_summary** with 891 rows and a column name **body_text**. Here is my code + a bit pseudo code as I dont know how to write it exactly:

```
import time 

for i in tqdm(range(0,891)):
  # code to detect running time here
    df_summary['body_text'][i] = summary(df['body_text'][i])# perform the summary function with at most 120s 
  # when 120s is over but the summary function cannot finish than perform a preprocessing function instead and move to the next iteration
    df_summary['body_text'][i] = preprocess(df['body_text'][i])
```

Note that if the function summary can run in at most 120s or under that limit time, it wont run the fallback function **preproces**s and then move to the next iteration.

How can I achieve this? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It is not 100% corresponding to my case.

Comment: How many % are missing?

Comment: I dont see they called the fallback function... Can you propose a solution corresponding to my case?

Comment: I propose to use one of the solutions shown in the question I've linked and add the code for calling a fallback function on top.

Comment: Actually, maybe add the fallback function in the exception case? I dont quiet understand their codes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer :

```
import sys
import threading
try:
    import thread
except ImportError:
    import _thread as thread


def exit_after(s):
    '''
    use as decorator to exit process if 
    function takes longer than s seconds
    '''

    def quit_function(fn_name):
        # print to stderr, unbuffered in Python 2.
        sys.stderr.flush() # Python 3 stderr is likely buffered.
        thread.interrupt_main() # raises KeyboardInterrupt

    def outer(fn):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            timer = threading.Timer(s, quit_function, args=[fn.__name__])
            timer.start()
            try:
                result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                timer.cancel()
            return result
        return inner
    return outer

# I DIDN'Y WRITE THE CODE ABOVE I GOT IT FROM THERE : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call

@exit_after(120) # the function will kill itself after 120 seconds
def process(data): 
    summary(data)

for i in tqdm(range(0,891)):
    try:
        df_summary['body_text'][i] = process(df['body_text'][i])
    except KeyboardInterrupt: # took over 120 seconds
        df_summary['body_text'][i] = preprocess(df['body_text'][i])
```

After 120s, it will stop processing and will run the preprocess function.
Tell me if you don't understand something

Comment: I run until iteration 45 I got this error: ```KeyError: 45

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:
-> 2900                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2901 
   2902         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 45``` Can you check?

Comment: i don't think this comes from my code

Comment: I test the iteration 46 it's fine but I am not really sure what cause the problem for this...

Comment: it has to come from your process function or something since the error refers to a file called "base.py"

Comment: Anyway if it's coming from my code I can't do anything about it because I just copied other peoples code and adapted it to work with your code